# Simplify decision whether to use one object or another in Java

Tags: java

I have a `Transaction` class which looks like this:

```
public class Transaction {

  private Transaction parentTransaction;
  private long amount;
  private String orderNumber;
}
```

So it has a field which points to another `Transaction`.

There is also a method like this:

```java
public void build(Transaction transaction) {
    final long amount = transaction.getParentTransaction() == null ? transaction.getAmount() : transaction.getParentTransaction().getAmount();
    final String orderNumber = transaction.getParentTransaction() == null ? transaction.getOrderNumber() : transaction.getParentTransaction().getOrderNumber();
    // same pattern follows for more fields...


    // do other stuff...
}
```

Depending on whether a `parentTransaction` exists, e.g. the `amount` field shall be used from the `parentTransaction` or the `transaction`. What I don't like about this approach is the repetitive usage of the `transaction.getParentTransaction() == null ? ...` term.

Is there some pattern or apporach how I could avoid this?

Comment: Maybe an Optional<T> could help? It has nice operators.

Comment: Use Optional instead?

Comment: Just do `if(transaction.getParentTransaction() != null) transaction = transaction.getParentTransaction();` right at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Optional as suggested by others:

```
public void build(Transaction transaction) {
        
        Transaction parentTransactionElseTransaction = Optional.of(transaction)
                .map(t -> t.getParentTransaction())
                .orElse(transaction);

        final long amount = parentTransactionElseTransaction.getAmount();
        final String orderNumber = parentTransactionElseTransaction.getOrderNumber();

        // same pattern follows for more fields...
        // do other stuff...
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Optional is an option, but I think there is a much simpler solution:

```
public void build(Transaction transaction) {
    Transaction buildFrom = transaction.getParentTransaction() == null ? transaction : transaction.getParentTransaction();
    ...
    String orderNumber = buildFrom.getOrderNumber();
```

If you don't like that mix of abstractions, you can go one step further and put that `? :` line into a small helper method.

Comment: That helper method [does already exist (JDK 9+)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)): `Transaction buildFrom = Objects.requireNonNullElse( transaction.getParentTransaction(), transaction);`

Answer (score 1):

Use some minor refactoring with Optional:

```
public void build(Transaction transaction) {
    Transaction t = Optional.of(transaction).map(Transaction::getParent).orElse(transaction);
    long amount = t.getAmount(); 
    String orderNumber = t.getOrderNumber();
    // etc
}
```

Comment: If you really don’t like `(parent != null? parent: transaction)`, you can use [`Objects.requireNonNullElse(parent, transaction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)), still without a need for `Optional`. And even better, `Transaction toUse = Objects.requireNonNullElse(transaction.getParentTransaction(), transaction);` followed by using just `toUse` instead of repeating the conditional over and over again.

Comment: Yup, using the Objects class is much better. I would recommend not to use Optional for such simple conditions, it's an antipattern where you are creating an extra object just to check if it is absent or present. Simply use Objects class or an if statement.

Comment: @Holger I like the `requireNonNullElse` appraoch but unfortunately it's not available in Java 8.

Comment: @RobertStrauch you can easily make your own, `public static <T> T requireNonNullElse(T object, T fallback) { return object != null? object: fallback; }` and use that until you migrate to a higher Java version and switch to the JDK implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void build(Transaction transaction) {
        final long amount = Optional.ofNullable(transaction.getParentTransaction()).orElse(transaction).getAmount();
        final String orderNumber = Optional.ofNullable(transaction.getParentTransaction()).orElse(transaction).getOrderNumber();
        // same pattern follows for more fields...


        // do other stuff...
    }
```

Can use `Optional.ofNullable().orElse()` here